# Filter by 2 different category value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want a field to show if it has a category of either 2 values from 2 different sub fields.

Im not quite sure how to do this though with 2 different subfields.

Here is an exmaple im trying to demo to show how I would like it to work:

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('team_profile')): 
    $category = get_sub_field('category');
    $category_2 = get_sub_field('category_2');
    if($category=='copyclearance')
        if($category_2=='anothercat'){ ?>
            <li class="col-lg-2 teamProfile">
                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('profile_image'); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                <h2><?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?></h2>
                <p class="jobTitle"><?php the_sub_field('job_title'); ?></p>
            </li>
            <?php 
        } 
endwhile; ?>
```

This is my working version with just one category filter (but I need 2):

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('team_profile')): 
    $category = get_sub_field('category');
    if ($category=='copyclearance') { ?>
        <li class="col-lg-2 teamProfile">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('profile_image'); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
            <h2><?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?></h2>
            <p class="jobTitle"><?php the_sub_field('job_title'); ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php 
    } 
endwhile; ?>
```

So this would work, by looking to see if anything has been posted in either `$category` or in `$category_2` then displaying all of them results.  NOT using the 2 to filter specifically i.e only showing posts that are in both `$category` and `$category_2`

Comment: Sidenote: Make sure you always use `{}` with your if statements. In your first example you could run into some trouble if you don't, and it's always best practice because it makes code much more clear and you avoid bugs that are hard to track down. Apple recently had a huge fiasco as a result of this - start early and be vigilant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of nesting your `if` statements, use the or operator:

```
if($category=='copyclearance' || $category=='anothercat') {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to do more than two, I recommend using an array:

```
$valid_cats = array('copyclearance', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'etc');

if(in_array($category, $valid_cats)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand - if you want to make sure two categories are present, use the and operator: `if($category=='cat1' && $category=='cat2')`.